# Timeseries Objects Duplicate Entries

Tags: database, time-series, nosql

I am working on a time series NoSQL database where I need to stamp values on an hourly basis. However, some times the values might stay the same. If the values, which are coming from a third party API, are the same, should I store them as duplicates or wait until the values are updated? In the first case, it results in many duplicates but I am not sure if it's the right approach? Any thoughts?

Answer (score 0):

If values stays the same then it is not a duplicate entry as timestamp has changed.

Comment: I know it's not but other than the timestamp, the rest of the values are duplicates, right?

Comment: It is still a valid entry in my opinion.

Comment: so you think storing it as a separate entry is fine?

Comment: You are storing as it is

Answer (score 0):

If the history of value changes is important, I would store this information in additional columns. It's what NoSQL is for, right?

- received_time
- update_time
- modified-time
- repeat-counter
- value

Comment: So would you store duplicate values or one value with a counter?

Comment: You don't seem to need to store value, otherwise this would be a typical versioning use case and it's handled in NoSQL, e.g. HBase really well.. Your emphasis appears to be on keeping track of change times, hence I'd store the last value and the counter.